# Are 'dynamic' balance boards better for balance training than 'static' ones?

Tags: stability, balance

I have a simple round balance board with contact point at the middle. I've tried vew-do, with rolling balance point, that moves along the rail on the bottom of the board. It was terribly hard, I've managed not to fail for about 2 seconds... Those things are also much more expensive...

But are they actually better for building balance (for trail running, climbing etc)  and training stabilization muscles? Or they are just for training balance with more fun and adrenaline?

Answer (score -1):

You do not build balance, balance is a muscle keeping your body from collapsing.

When you walk on a rope, you are not using a magic sense called balance. Your  hip muscles are working to keep you from falling.

When you do a handstand, you don't wish upon a star that your trunk doesn't collapse and you fall...instead your wrist and shoulders are actively working to keep you standing on your hands. 
[image]

As you see in the picture, it doesn't even matter if the trunk collapses or is relaxed, all that matters is the strength in the shoulders and wrists.

Balance is just strength, they are interchangeable.

Things that put the body in uncomfortable positions to "build balance" are often used to build strength like bamboo bars of balance pads, but their efficacy is anecdotally really well reviewed by strength coaches.

However they haven not been clinically studied yet.

Comment: -1 balance is a physical attribute relevant for sports. One uses the muscles to demonstrate balance but it is its own aspect of fitness that must be trained independently. It is in no way interchangeable with strength.